# Relationship to "jump" through M2M relationships in SqlAlchemy (User -> Role -> Permission)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, relationship, m2m

I am trying to model a very typical permission structure where a `User` model (the human user of my website) can be assigned to some `Roles`, and each of those `Roles` has some `Permissions`.

It would be really helpful if I could get a `relationship` from `User` straight to `Permission`. That way, I could fetch a *user* (instance) from the database and just do `user.permissions` to get his permissions, put some filtering to check if a user has a specific `Permission`, have them pre-loaded... in sum: all the goodies that come with a `relationship`.

A `viewonly` relationship would be perfectly fine. As mentioned by Mike Bayer in [a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8962098/289011), I can't be writing to `User.permissions` because we don't not know which 'Role' to use or *where* to insert it.

I have created two intermediate tables:

```
User -- M2M --> Role(s) -- M2M --> Permission(s)
 |                                     ^
 +-------- user.permissions -----------+
```

- `users_roles` to connect the `user` to its `roles` through their primary key (the ID)
- and `roles_permissions` to connect each `role` to its `permissions`,

This is my table structure (simplified for the question, but even the full version is really typical and... simple)

```
class User(DeclarativeBase, Mixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    email = Column(String(25), nullable=False)

_users_roles = Table('users_roles', DeclarativeBase.metadata,
    Column('user_id', ForeignKey('users.id', ...
    Column('role_id', ForeignKey('roles.id', ...
    PrimaryKeyConstraint('user_id', 'role_id',),
)    

class Role(DeclarativeBase, Mixin):
    __tablename__ = 'roles'

    name = Column(Text(), nullable=False, unique=True)
    users = relationship("User", secondary=_users_roles, backref="roles")

_roles_permissions = Table('roles_permissions', DeclarativeBase.metadata,
    Column('role_id', ForeignKey('roles.id',  ...
    Column('permission_id', ForeignKey('permissions.id', ...
    PrimaryKeyConstraint('role_id', 'permission_id',),
)

class Permission(DeclarativeBase, Mixin):
    __tablename__ = 'permissions'

    key = Column(Text, nullable=False, unique=True,)
```

I saw [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27298936/289011) that looks very promising, yet I don't seem to be able to make it work. Honestly, I've been trying a lot of combinations and I'd say that the furthest I got was with this:

```
permissions = relationship('Permission',
    secondary="""join(User, users_roles, 
                     User.id == users_roles.c.user_id
                 ).join(roles_permissions, 
                    users_roles.c.role_id == roles_permissions.c.role_id
                ).join(
                  Permission, roles_permissions.c.permission_id == Permission.id
               )""",
    viewonly=True,
)
```

Which gives me this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Relationship User.permissions 
could not determine any unambiguous local/remote column pairs 
based on join condition and remote_side arguments.  Consider 
using the remote() annotation to accurately mark those elements
of the join condition that are on the remote side of the relationship.
```

Any hints would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The secondary should not include the related tables themselves, but just the association between them:

```
permissions = relationship(
    'Permission',
    secondary="""join(users_roles, roles_permissions, 
                      users_roles.c.role_id == roles_permissions.c.role_id)""",
    viewonly=True,
)
```

Having the to-be-joined tables in the secondary confuses the automation that is trying to find the foreign key relationships between `User` and `Permission`, through the secondary.

Comment: OMG... Hours!!... I spent hours trying different combinations of _things_!! Thank you very much.

Comment: Is the concept here that the join effectively creates a single association table?

Comment: @SuperShoot Pretty much. You can use about any table (that has the foreign keys present) as the secondary, be it a result of a join, select, or some such: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/join_conditions.html#composite-secondary-joins. Due to how SQLA handles deduplicating entities, it is not a problem even if the join produces the same permission id multiple times.

Comment: _it is not a problem even if the join produces the same permission id multiple times._

I can assess for this. I created a test where a `user` belongs to two different roles, each of them with the same permission, and in my `user.permissions` relationship I only get one `Permission` instance even if I don't specify `collection_class = set` in the `relationship`. This is something that worried me a little (getting duplicate permissions) but no: it doesn't happen... It's working great :+1: